# How can i delete multiple images from multiple folders using python

Tags: python, image, directory, picturegallery

I am having 100 folders and each folder is having 1000 images. i need to delete 900 images from each folder.

The images deleting can be random and i need 100 images to be left in each folder.

Is there any python script that can help.

i tried the following code

```
import os
import random

for folder in 'owais_images_dataset/donuts':  # Go over each folder path
files = os.listdir('owais_images_dataset/donuts')  # Get filenames in current folder
files = random.sample(files, 900)  # Pick 900 random files
for file in files:  # Go over each file name to be deleted
    f = os.path.join("owais_images_dataset/donuts", "")  # Create valid path to file
    os.remove(f)  # Remove the file
```

and got this error

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-b1f2c957d985> in <module>()
  7     for file in files:  
  8         f = os.path.join("owais_images_dataset/donuts", "") 
  9         os.remove(f)  
  PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 
  'owais_images_dataset/donuts/'
```

Comment: but i dont know any script ... thats why i need help ...

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html everything you need is in there

Comment: Hi @OwaisQayum, It is always better to show what have you attempted. SO is a place to help developers, not a place to ask for scripts.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. We can help you to fix mistakes, to find find how to use a piece of the standard library or from another module, but you are supposed to do some research and show your best attempt. I am sorry, but this question is off topic here.

Comment: i have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import random

for folder in folder_paths:  # Go over each folder path
    files = os.listdir(folder)  # Get filenames in current folder
    files = random.sample(files, 900)  # Pick 900 random files
    for file in files:  # Go over each file name to be deleted
        f = os.path.join(folder, file)  # Create valid path to file
        os.remove(f)  # Remove the file
```

Comment: I tried the code 

`import os
import random

for folder in 'owais_images_dataset/donuts':  
    files = os.listdir('owais_images_dataset/donuts') 
    files = random.sample(files, 900) 
    for file in files: 
        f = os.path.join("owais_images_dataset/donuts", "") 
        os.remove(f)  `

and got the following error

`
os.remove(f)  # Remove the file

PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'owais_images_dataset/donuts/'
`

Comment: One: Python is whitespace-indented. The code you added is not properly indented. Two: do you really have the appropriate permissions? Use `sudo` if you know what you are doing.